# Browser fingerprint for client unique identification

Tags: javascript, browser

I need to somehow identify the client mechine connecting my server. I tried extracting the MAC address using an applet but it didn't work. Through my searchs around the net, I came across technology called fingerprint.

Basically, using [Valve JS library](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintJS), I can generate some unique ID based on: "agent string, screen color depth, language, installed plugins with supported mime types, timezone offset and other capabilities, such as local storage and session storage"

This suppose to be accurate for about 90% of times - which is good enough for me.

My question is this:
Lets say I update my flash plugin.. does it mean that I will get a different fignerprint ID?

If so, this is not a very rliable technology for identification.

Anyone know?

Comment: are cookies not an option? sry I know nothing about that library, so I can't help with that

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask the creator of the app (on GitHub) the question?

Comment: I didn't use it but yes, it will be marked as a different id, it basically generates a hash string depending on the information you mentioned and any changes in your machine/browser will cause marked it as a different one, AFAIK about browser fingerprint.

Comment: The "read more" section has an interesting comment at the end: "After viewing the results we removed the fingerprinting because of poor identification, especially with mobile devices."

Comment: Thanks... I wont use it.